# Silverlight and WebService

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-4.0

I am working on a silverlight project which is a kind of virtual order. At the end it completes the input data and sends them as a mail . However you cannot send mails in silverlight because it doesnt allow .NET libraries which I use for sending mails (System.Net.Mail) so I am using a web service to send that mail . I use these functions :

1. In silverlight

   ```
   public static void SendAsMail()
   {
       MailServiceSoapClient client = new MailServiceSoapClient(); // Client of WebService
       client.SendMailAsync(output.ToString()); // output is the text of mail
   }
   ```
2. In WebService

   ```
   [WebService(Namespace = "http://www.mydomain.sk/")]
   [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
   [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
       public class MailService : System.Web.Services.WebService
       {
           [WebMethod]
           public bool SendMail(string mail_text)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("connected");
               // function which sends mail
               return true;
           }
       }
   ```

   I have added the MessageBox function to know if i have accessed the WebService. When I click the button which connects to WebService, it does nothing.

I don't know how to fix this, please help

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can use a messagebox from a web service which runs inside IIS and has no user interface, this is not a windows application.

Try to replace messagebox.show with a logging method either in the windows EventLog or on a text file and check how it works.

Comment: It didn't work before, when there was only the function. can i use throw new Exception()?

Comment: show the code you are using to send the email. No, in any case you have to throw a more specialized exception, System.Exception is a class to use to derive other exceptions and should not be thrown like that...

Comment: i think it doesnt depend on the function im using beause when i leave the function blank and I leave there just : return true; it doesnt return anything

Comment: of course it does not return anything, in the SL side you are calling it with Async but you are not catching the completed event, search for examples on how to call web services in SilverLight and how to process their results...

Comment: ok i have added handler : client.SendMailCompleted and there i am catching the result but it still doesnt work

Comment: static void client_SendMailCompleted(object sender, SendMailCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            MessageBox.Show(e.Result.ToString());             
        }

Answer (score 0):

Make a service method that returns a value.
Then you can use that to return any error messages or success messages